# How to store action.payload in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, redux-toolkit

I want to set `state.name` to "Alex" and `age` plus one after click the Login function, and set email to `action.payload`.

Here is my user state slice

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: { value: { name: "", age: 0, email: "" } },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value.name = "Alex"
      state.value.age = state.value.age + 1
      state.value.email = action.payload
    }, 
  }
})
```

Here is my `useDispatch`

```
function Login() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(login({ email: 'example@gmail.com' }))
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

There is an error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {email}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I am using Redux Toolkit.

Comment: your error is not exactly where the code you posted I guess and also you should set `email` as `state.value.email= action.payload.email`

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are likely selecting this `state.user.value` state in a component and rendering the constituent parts, i.e. `value.name`, `value.age`, and `value.email`. This is fine until you update the `state.user.value.email` to have the payload value of `{ email: 'example@gmail.com' }` when dispatching the `login` action. This makes the `value.email` an object and unrenderable.

Either dispatch the `login` action with the *exact* payload value you want to save into state:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch(login('example@gmail.com'));
  }}
>
  Login
</button>
```

or unpack the `email` property from the payload correctly in the case reducer:

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    value: {
      name: "",
      age: 0,
      email: ""
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value.name = "Alex";
      state.value.age = state.value.age + 1;
      state.value.email = action.payload.email;
    },
  }
});
```

I would suggest also simplifying the state to unnest the actual values you want to store.

Example:

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    name: "",
    age: 0,
    email: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.name = "Alex";
      state.age = state.age + 1;
      state.email = action.payload; // { payload: 'example@gmail.com' }
    },
  }
});
```

...

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

...

<>
  Name: {user.name}
  Age: {user.age}
  Email: {user.email}
</>
```